# PowerShell Get-Content Foreach-object to replace the current line with a value from the next

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to replace a value in the current line with a value from the next line using PowerShell. Something like:

```
gci | foreach {(gc $_.FullName) | foreach-object { 
$a = #Here I want to use a regex to strip the ProductId from the next line
$_ -replace 'In Stock', "[[Availability ProductId=$a]]" }}
```

Can this be done?

Comment: You will have to give some concrete example of what you want

Comment: I think it doesn't work this way, but I updated my example for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Not directly inside the `ForEach-Object`, no. You can cheat a little:

```
$x = $null
Get-Content c:\mypath\file.htm <# who puts files there? #> |
  ForEach-Object {
    if ($x -eq $null) {
      $x = $_
    } else {
      $x -replace 'This Value', $_ # or whatever you need from the next line
    }
  }
```

Another way is to just use the normal way:

```
$lines = Get-Content c:\mypath\file.htm
$replacedLines = $(
  for ($i = 0; $i -lt $lines.Length - 1; $i++) {
    $lines[$i] -replace 'This Value', $lines[$i+1]
  }
)
```